# Approximate number of rows and execution time for query

Tags: database, oracle

I would like to assess the number of lines and execution time for my query **before** executing it. Is it possible?

Comment: How should be DB engine know the execution time before execution? Same with lines. DB needs to execute to find the lines.

Comment: well, before executing a query optimizer looks at statistics and chooses execution plan. I thought it might also estimate overall time and rows for query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A query plan can show you how many rows the optimizer estimates will be returned (or modified) and how long the optimizer estimates a query will run.  Because these estimates are tied to, among other things, the statistics on the tables, however, it is entirely possible that they will be wildly incorrect.

If I take a simple query, however

```
SQL> explain plan for select count(*) from emp where deptno = 10;

Explained.

SQL> select *
  2    from table( dbms_xplan.display );

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2083865914

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     1 |     3 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |      |     1 |     3 |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |     3 |     9 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("DEPTNO"=10)

14 rows selected.
```

Oracle expects that a full table scan of the `EMP` table, filtering out the rows where `deptno = 10` will return 3 rows and take 1 second (the `Rows` and `Time` columns from the query plan for the row with `id = 2`).  Oracle expects the `COUNT(*)` aggregation on the row with `id = 1` to reduce that to 1 row.  So, on the row with `id = 0`, Oracle expects the `SELECT` statement to return 1 row and to run for 1 second.

Comment: @damluar - I'm not sure what the question is.  The process would be the same regardless of the number of steps in the plan.  If you are just concerned about the overall performance of the query, you can always look at the `id = 0` row.  If you are interested in breaking down individual steps, you'd need to look a the information for that step.

Comment: In my case it's OLAP query, joining quite some tables, so I'm not sure if Oracle can give more or less decent estimation.

Comment: @damluar - The quality of the estimate is far more down to the quality of the statistics (including things like histograms on columns) than the number of steps in the plan or the number of tables that get joined.  And, of course, what "decent" is depends heavily on what you plan on doing with the information.  If the statistics are reasonably accurate, the estimates should be correct within an order of magnitude and will likely be correct to within a factor of, say, 2 (standard disclaimer that your mileage may vary).